# structs does not see each other

Tags: c++, c, struct

I have a trouble about structs. I have two structs and one of them includes a pointer member that points to other one and this situation is valid for both.

For example,

```
struct A{

    B *x;
}

struct B{

    A *y;

}
```

Finally, I tried to put these two structs into a big struct because member of a struct can see another member of it ,but I cannot handle this problem.

Comment: forward declare `B`: `struct B;`.